# setup.py 中のExtensionの書き方について。

Tags: python, c++

C++でPython用の拡張モジュールを作成しました。ソースコード(pymodule.cpp)は自作のインクルードファイルを含みます。具体的には以下のような形です。

```
#include <Python.h>
#include "head.hpp"
```

head.hppには関数宣言のみを含み、定義はhead.cppに書いてあります。
ここからpython用モジュールを作成するためにはどのようなstup.pyを書けばよろしいでしょうか。

Comment: 直前の質問と類似の範囲/内容では無いですか？ 直前の質問の記述内容を詳細化して充実させたほうが良い気がしますが。あるいはC++でPythonの拡張モジュールを作成するTutorial記事を探して、いったんはその通りに作成してみるとか。

Comment: 直前の質問については自分で解決しました。ありがとうございました。結局、この質問と関連するのですがsetup.pyでモジュール化する際に分けて書いた方のcppファイルとリンクされてないのが原因だったようです。なのでこちらの質問をさせて頂きました。チュートリアルはかなり漁ってはいるのですがこの質問に該当するようなものがなくて…

Comment: 公式のドキュメントも参照してみてください。[拡張モジュールについて記述する](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/distutils/setupscript.html#describing-extension-modules)

Comment: OSやIDE等の環境によって違うかもしれませんが、こんな記事が参考になるかもしれません。[Python 用 C++ 拡張機能の作成](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/python/working-with-c-cpp-python-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022), [【Python C API入門】C/C++で拡張モジュール作ってPythonから呼ぶ -前編-](https://cpp-learning.com/python_c_api_step1/), [【Python C API入門】C/C++で拡張モジュール作ってPythonから呼ぶ -後編-](https://cpp-learning.com/python_c_api_step2/), [IDEでPythonのC/C++拡張モジュールを開発する](https://hackmd.io/@miurahr/By-a1-rlF)